# I am trying to filter a list by SharePoint group, SharePoint 2013 On-Premise

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-on-prem

I am trying to filter a list based upon SharePoint group membership.
So if a person belongs to a certain group he sees their documents.0
Or (simpler) they click on a document library view "sales" or "engineering", to get there.

A kind of [Me] filter but then for a set of document library views.
When a person creates a document, then a workflow (i think) sets a document property based upon a group he is member of.

Would that be possible using SharePoint Designer and Workflows?, I'm not allowed to use visual studio here.

Comment: yes it is possible using SP Designer

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Large Number of Groups which will be coming up in the list. If there are 3-4 groups whose users you need to configure, I suggest you create 3-4 views with filtering value for the column containing the group name and then apply a **Audience Targeting** for each view.

This will not allow users of other group to see other views.